# Variable-length form submissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

I'd like to create a form_for statement which allows the user to select elements one-by-one from a drop down menu (or an auto-complete field). As the user selects each item, they should be displayed in list format at the top of the screen. When the user has finished selecting elements, the form can be submitted and the list of selected elements is sent to the receiving controller action.

Can someone tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Chosen is what you need.

Take a look at:
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: That looks like an interesting approach. However, the user wouldn't be selecting from a pre-defined set of elements. I realized that my original question is misleading because is said "auto-complete," implying that there is a set of elements to choose from. However, my current goal is for the user to type in a pair of strings for each element to be added to the list.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much Laurens. This is much closer to what I need. 

Do you have any suggestions for how I can use this in a way that allows the user to easily submit a set of name-email pairs?

Comment: Currently I don't have the time to do a writeup for this.

This should get you on the right track:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3 
Also check out the other rails casts about complex forms, hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812003/adding-fields-dynamically-in-a-nested-model-form-in-rails-3 has a good answer as well.

Comment: It says I need a reputation of 15 before I can vote up answers. Sorry.

Comment: You don't have to vote up, you can mark the arrow left from the answer to 'accept' the answer.