# Nested Model Form - Render not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm new in rails and need some help creating a Nested form.

I have this in teams/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :players do |builder| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'players_field', :f => builder %>
<% end %>


<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

What I want is create a list of players in the team form. The problem is that the render don't work and players_field.html.erb don't render.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tableRow">
  <tr>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

TR is added to the table with js.

UPDATE:

Another problem appear now :/

This is my js:

```
 var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
 newRow.innerHTML =  "<td>"+ counter +"</td>"+
                     "<%= f.text_field :name %>"+
                     "<%= f.text_field :position %>"+;
 document.getElementById("tableRow").appendChild(newRow);
```

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000000288dd38>:0x007f77cc1226e0>
```

Why I can't add this ?

Comment: You mention `players_field.html.erb` doesn't render. The file should be named `_players_field.html.erb`.

Comment: Yes i forgot to say but my file is named well, _players_field.html.erb

Comment: @jony17 There are a couple of issues here. First, when passing data to a partial, you must use either `<%= render :partial => 'players_field', :locals => {:f => builder} %>` or just `<%= render 'players_field', :f => builder %>`. Second, you cannot run ruby code from within javascript. The string `<%= f.text_field :name %>` will not be executed on the client side (only js will be executed). It must be done on the server side.

Comment: If you need help with dynamically adding nested form elements, have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812003/adding-fields-dynamically-in-a-nested-model-form-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block

```
<%= f.fields_for :players do |builder| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'players_field', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

is basically a loop through `@team.players`. It might be the case that `@team` simply doesn't have any players to loop through. To show the form for at least one player you can change this to

```
f.fields_for :players, @team.players.build do |builder| ...
```