# Rails 3.2.11 - create associated object on the fly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following models:

**Document.rb**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :order
  attr_accessible :docfile, :print_format, :user_comment, :paper_type
  has_attached_file :docfile,
                    :styles => {
                      :thumb => "100x100>"
                    },
                    :url => "/order_documents/:order_number/:style/:id.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/order_documents/:order_number/:style/:id.:extension"

  validates_attachment_size :docfile, :less_than => 100.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :docfile,
                                    :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip']

end
```

**Order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents, :allow_destroy => true

  DELIVERY_COMMENT_ROWS_SIZE = 2
  DELIVERY_COMMENT_COLS_SIZE = 40

  validates_associated :documents
  validates :delivery_street, :delivery_address, :presence => true

end
```

I have **Orders_controller.rb:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    unless params[:add_document]
      @order.documents.build
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    current_user.orders &lt;&lt; @order
    respond_to do |wants|
      if @order.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Заказ создан успешно.'
        wants.html {redirect_to my_orders_path}
        wants.xml { render :xml =&gt @order.to_xml }
      else
        wants.html { render :action => "new" }
        wants.xml {render :xml =&gt @order.errors}
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**new.erb.html** for "new" action:

```
<%= form_for @order, :url => orders_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |order| %>
  <%= order.fields_for :documents do |document| %>
    <%= render :partial => "add_document", :locals => {:document => document} %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="documents"></div>
  <%= link_to "add document...", new_order_path(:add_document => true), remote: true %>
  <%= submit_tag 'save order', :class => 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

And partial **_add_document.erb:**

```
 <%= document.file_field :docfile %>
 <%= document.select(:print_format, Document::PRINT_FORMAT) %>
 <%= document.select(:paper_type, Document::PAPER_TYPE) %>
 <%= document.text_area :user_comment, :rows => Document::USER_COMMENT_ROWS_SIZE, :cols => Document::USER_COMMENT_COLS_SIZE %>
```

I have a problem to create a new document for order on the fly (using JQuery).
I have **new.js.erb:**

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "add_document", :locals => { :document => @order.documents.build }) %>').appendTo($('#documents'));
```

but get errors:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `file_field' for #<Document:0x695c3d0>)
```

Help please. What jquery code I have to write to a file new.js.erb?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this piece of code in your jQuery: `:document => @order.documents.build`.

When you call the partial with `:document => @order.documents.build` you are passing in an instance of the `Document` object, when what you really want to pass in is a `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` object.

You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812936/1193642), it may help you out.

Also, it seems to me you have a logic error in your `OrdersController`:

Shouldn't this:

```
unless params[:add_document]
  @order.documents.build
end
```

Be this:

```
if params[:add_document]
  @order.documents.build
end
```

Since I presume you would only want to build the relation if `{:add_document => true}` is passed in.