# Achieving customised nested_form in Rails4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with `Rals4 and nested form`, I wanted to achieve like below,

[image]

Where their will be a table after add button(ref to: `link_to_add_fields` from nested form) it should store into the table temporary in the same form which can be editable and delete.

After adding required rows their will be `main submit button` which will store all nested_form data(`from generated table`) into the database.

How to achieve above scenario please refer me the some code stuff and ref links.

Comment: a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812003/adding-fields-dynamically-in-a-nested-model-form-in-rails-3) that question also links to some railscasts you might want to watch...

Comment: It won't helped me...!!!